# C# async await weird behavior

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm new to C# and for now I'm trying to understand async/await feautures. So I have created small sandbox app:

```
namespace sandbox
{
public class Test
{
    public async Task<string> GetItemsAsync()
    {
        var a = await Task1();
        var b = await Task2();
        var c = await Task3();

        return a + b + c;
    }

    public string GetItems()
    {
        return _T1() + _T2() + _T3();
    }

    private readonly int cycles = 100000000;

    private async Task<string> Task1()
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(_T1);
    }

    private async Task<string> Task2()
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(_T2);
    }

    private async Task<string> Task3()
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(_T3);
    }

    // long running operation
    private string _T1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++) ;
        for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++) ;
        return "One";
    }

    // long running operation
    private string _T2()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++) ;
        for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++) ;
        return "Two";
    }

    // long running operation
    private string _T3()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++) ;
        for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++) ;
        return "Three";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new Test();

        Console.WriteLine("Async");
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var result = t.GetItemsAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(result.Result);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.WriteLine("Sync");
        sw.Restart();
        var strResult = t.GetItems();
        Console.WriteLine(strResult);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

But the result is weird:

```
Async
OneTwoThree
1754
Sync
OneTwoThree
1506
```

Async method runs longer than similar sync one. For me it's look like async methods runs synchronously but I cant figure out why.

Comment: Because your awaiting all of them syncrhonously.

Comment: by awaiting the Task's you are changing it from a Asynchronous to Synchronous, the await keyword translates a pause the current task and don't continue until the awaited task completes

Comment: Using the await will make the code run synchronously AND also add the overhead of creating a state machine (each time you use `await`) so its also slower than running them synchronously.

Comment: This question appears to be a magnet for people who either (a) don't understand `async`/`await` or (b) can't explain them

Comment: @BenVoigt: Sadly this question is not *unique* in that regard. :-)

Comment: @amergan, can you describe for us what you believed the `await` operator does?  I am interested to know how people's intuitions about programming language constructs lead them astray. An await is an *asynchronous wait*; the intention was to give you the intuition that you will be *waiting* for the result of the task, but *still doing other work on the current thread* while you're waiting. In what ways did we fail to give you the correct intuition, and how could it be better?

Comment: @EricLippert for me await means: start job and wait in the background for the result. In the meantime do the rest job. e.g. await Task1 -> start Task1 and go further.

Comment: But the call already starts the task; you have a task in hand, the task is already a task. Await doesn't *start* anything, it *waits for something to finish*, hence the name.

Comment: Put another way: an await is a *temporary return*.  Await means "if this task is already finished then get its result; if it is not finished then tell the task to schedule the remainder of this method after the task completes, and return to my caller."

Comment: @amergan: I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that may help you out.

Answer (score 4):

Because of this:

```
var a = await Task1();
var b = await Task2();
var c = await Task3();
```

Before you even start `Task2` you have waited for `Task1` to complete. So you're not running them in parallel, you're running them in sequence.

If you want to start all 3 tasks, then wait for them to complete you would have to change this method to this:

```
public async Task<string> GetItemsAsync()
{
    var t1 = Task1();
    var t2 = Task2();
    var t3 = Task3();

    var a = await t1;
    var b = await t2;
    var c = await t3;

    return a + b + c;
}
```

Or just the last part:

```
return (await t1) + (await t2) + (await t3);
```

Additionally, this code is an antipattern:

```
private async Task<string> Task3()
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(_T3);
}
```

You don't need `async/await` here because *you're not doing any more work in this method after your sub-task returns*.

Instead simply rewrite this method (and its siblings) to this:

```
private Task<string> Task3()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(_T3);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not started the tasks"? That is the responsibility of those 3 methods, which clearly start new tasks. It is not my responsibility to start a task *if that task was returned back to me*. That is the responsibility of *whatever it was that returned it*. Anyway, these tasks are clearly started, `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: Apologises i misread their code and didn't notice the starts inside the task methods

Comment: The op *could* elide `async`/`await`; I wouldn't go so far as to call it an anti-pattern, though. What is *definitely* an anti-pattern is the use of `StartNew` without specifying a task scheduler (should use `Task.Run` instead). Also, you could make a strong case that returning a `StartNew`/`Run` task is also an anti-pattern (synchronous code should have synchronous APIs; the *caller* should decide whether to push to the thread pool).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the intention was to make all three tasks do the job in parallel. That is one of options how it could be accomplished:

```
public async Task<string> GetItemsAsync()
{
    var a = Task1();
    var b = Task2();
    var c = Task3();

    return string.Concat(await Task.WhenAll(a, b, c));
}
```